# Select days from schedule

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So I made this code :

```
SELECT 
    day.weekday
FROM
    day,
    event,
    event_date
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT 
            day.weekday
        FROM
            day)
        AND event.event_id = event_date.event_id
        AND event.day= day.day
GROUP BY day.weekday
```

It's working , but is there any other way to do it with EXSISTS ?

Comment: you should try sub-query  rather than join query

Comment: because join query take  more time than sub-query

Comment: @RajibGhosh but i do not use any join query as of now

Comment: but you need that which on you told

Comment: if you don't use *EXISTS* then you must use join query

Comment: please read this [subquery-optimization-with-exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    day.weekday
FROM
    day
    JOIN event ON event.day= day.day
    JOIN event_date ON event.event_id = event_date.event_id
GROUP BY 
    day.weekday
```